# Can I add non UTF-8 content to a .net resx file?

Tags: .net, utf-8, resources, resx

I'm using resx files to store localized content for some web apps. I've been asked to write a test mechanism to know if those resource files have non UTF-8 content on the values.

The resx files are XML files that on their header specify that they are UTF-8 encoded. So my question (maybe obvious or silly) is, can somebody add non UTF-8 strings into the resource file values?

I've already searched how to get the encoding for some string, but there is not bullet proof method, so I'm not sure if that test that I've been asked to create is either needed or possible...

EDIT
Just for clarification, the test should be performed within the localized app, and if the string is not a valid UTF-8 then display a default (localized) value

Answer (score 0):

To some degree, yes.  You can store plain ASCII text with no difficulty.

Outside of that?  Your best bet is to write a test for it.  Define some non-UTF8 strings in your code, store them in a .resx file (use `ResxRescourceWriter` for simplicity) and pull them back out.  Print them to the screen and see if they match.

It's certainly possible as well to change the encoding of a resx file.  If you do, you can then store strings encoded in that format.

Your best bet is to try and see what happens.

Edit: Based on clarification within a comment.

If you're needing to verify existing values, your best bet is likely to iterate over the resx files, doing a dump of all their text to a .txt file.

If you then open that file in Notepad++, you can specify UTF-8 encoding.  Anything that doesn't display readably is not UTF-8 text and will not display correctly when pulled from the resx.

Comment: The thing is that I have 3,000 resx files on that apps (don't ask why, I was there before I touched the code :P). So what it is needed to know is when I try to load some data of any of those thousands of files (when localizing), ensure that the string is a valid UTF-8 value

Comment: @pollirrata: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Plain ASCII *is* valid UTF-8.

Comment: I edited my question for clarification, since I don't want to do that manually.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I know.  I guess 'tongue-in-cheek' doesn't translate well to text.  Perhaps I should have encoded it in UTF-16?